# What is the proper way to encode a std::wstring to UTF-16 in a std::vector<unsigned char>?

Tags: c++, c++11, encoding, utf-16

I am attempting to encode a `std::wstring` to UTF-16 and pass it to a function which takes a pair of vector iterators. To accomplish this, I have tried the following.

```
std::vector<unsigned char> HashAlgorithm::ComputeHash(std::wstring value)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;

    std::string encodedString = converter.to_bytes(value);

    std::vector<unsigned char> encodedBytes(
        reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const *>(encodedString.c_str()),
        reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const *>(encodedString.c_str() + encodedString.size()));

    std::vector<unsigned char> hashedBytes = this->ComputeHash(encodedBytes.begin(), encodedBytes.end());
    return hashedBytes;
}
```

It works fine for the most part, except I know something is wrong because in debug mode I am seeing the following assertion on the return of `hashedBytes`, which smells like some kind of stack corruption.

[image: Debug Assertion - _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)]

What is causing this error and how can I prevent it?

**EDIT #1**

Here are the contents of support functions that I am using. I've been trying to break it down to figure out where the assertion is originating and why, but I've not been able to get a minimal reproduction yet.

```
std::vector<unsigned char> HashAlgorithm::ComputeHash(std::vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator begin, std::vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator end)
{
    this->Process(begin, end);
    std::vector<unsigned char> hashedBytes = this->Complete();

    return hashedBytes;
}

void HashAlgorithm::Process(std::vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator begin, std::vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator end)
{
    NTSTATUS status = BCryptHashData(this->hash, const_cast<unsigned char *>(&(*begin)), std::distance(begin, end), 0);
}

std::vector<unsigned char> HashAlgorithm::Complete()
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> result(this->outputSize);

    NTSTATUS status = BCryptFinishHash(this->hash, result.data(), (ULONG)result.size(), 0);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to convert the encoding or preserve it as-is? `wstring_convert::to_bytes` will turn it into a multibyte string by performing encoding conversion.

Comment: I want to perform any operations necessary to get the `std::wstring` into a sequence of encoded octets in UTF-16.

Comment: That's not answering the question, You can take UTF-16 and turn it into ASCII and then dump that as a sequence of bytes. However, that's useless if the receiver expects a byte sequence of UTF-16. So, again, do you want to produce an array of UTF-16 or actually perform a conversion into a different encoding.

Comment: I believe it answers the question just fine. I want to take a `std::wstring` in whatever encoding it may be and produce the equivalent UTF-16 octets. If the `std::wstring` is in UTF-8 or any other encoding, I want it to go to UTF-16 when it gets encoded into bytes. The function I am passing my vector into will take any encoding, but for cross compatibility I want to convert it into UTF-16.

Comment: Then you don't need to convert it. call `c_str()` on the wstring to get the underlying array. If you operate on it as if it's a `char*` then the correct size is `the_w_string.size() * sizeof(wchar_t)`

Comment: How can I guarantee what the encoding is then?

Comment: If you generate the string in your own code, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal for declaring a UTF-16 literal. If you receive the string from elsewhere, you'll need to determine if it's already UTF-16 or if you need to convert it. Also bear in mind that `wchar_t` is only 2 bytes on Windows, Linux is 4 bytes, so if you intend to be cross-platform, you might be better off sticking to `char16_t` and `std::u16string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::wstring` between Microsoft VC++ 2010 and 2015 are **not** backward compatible.

The problem is that `std::wstring` in the library code (VS 2010) and the client code (VS 2015) differ in size by 4 bytes. The newer version of `std::wstring` is larger at 32 bytes while the older one is 28 bytes. When passing these variables by value around, stack corruption occurs in the first 4 bytes of the smaller `std::wstring` and triggers the stack canaries used to guard against stack based exploits.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure you don't lose any data along the way you should hash the bytes directly:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> myClass::ComputeHash(std::wstring value)
{
    auto size_of_data = value.size()*sizeof(value[0]);
    auto pointer_to_data = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const *>(value.data());
    std::vector<unsigned char> encodedBytes(pointer_to_data,pointer_to_data+size_of_data);
    std::vector<unsigned char> hashedBytes = this->ComputeHash(encodedBytes.begin(),encodedBytes.end());
    return hashedBytes;
}
```

Try adding a banana ( \U0001F34C) to see what happens to your data as you step through. e.g. `std::wstring my_unicode_string{L"Test string \n"};` or `std::wstring wstr =  L"z\u00df\u6c34\U0001F34C"; // L"zß水"`. The second example might be better if your .cpp file isn't saved as unicode text.

You will probably get an exception thrown by `to_bytes` because only codepoints in the basic multilingual plane can be encoded into a single `wchar`. And if it does do the conversion for you it might have mapped different higher codepoints to similar bytes which would lead to the same hash for different strings.

Comment: So, what encoding will it be in and how can I ensure that it will be compatible with hashing being done in other languages that use Unicode strings such as C#?

Comment: Are you trying to mirror the [.NET logic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.computehash(v=vs.110).aspx) for these functions?

Comment: Not necessarily, but something familiar for our other developers. I do need compatibility between the two though.

Comment: If you want to ensure compatibility then you need precise specifications of how the hashes are calculated. You have UTF-16 which may include two symbols for some code points. And want to end up with a hash composed of a string of `unsigned char`s. But there are many ways to get from the one to the other. If you are getting the 'correct' hashes currently then you really should check to see what happens with the other unicode characters. A precise definition of 'compatibility' is essential.

Comment: It seems like [this](http://thomleigh.blogspot.com/2010/12/unicode-vs-ascii-md5-hashing.html) might be what you are trying to do.

Comment: The issue is actually the assertion being produced due to something related to my use of vectors, nothing related to the method I am doing the hashing in. If we could focus on that, I'd really appreciate it as that is what is stumping me right now. I do appreciate the encoding tips though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106283/discussion-between-flatmouse-and-michael-j-gray).